# Combining Spring boot and redis with docker-compose: Connection refused

Tags: java, spring, docker, docker-compose, redis

I am trying to do a basic docker container(s) with spring boot and MongoDB and redis. Mongo is just fine but connection can't be established between redis and spring boot although the configuration looks ok to me.

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "1234:1234"
    depends_on:
      - redis
      - db
  db:
    image: mongo
    hostname: mongodb
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
  redis:
    hostname: redis
    image: redis
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
```

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM adoptopenjdk:11
ARG JAR_FILE=target/*.jar
COPY ${JAR_FILE} app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

**Config.java:**

```
@Configuration
@EnableRedisRepositories
public class Config
{

    RedisStandaloneConfiguration standaloneConfiguration() {
        return new RedisStandaloneConfiguration("redis", 6379);
    }

    @Bean
    JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory() {
        return new JedisConnectionFactory(standaloneConfiguration());
    }

    @Bean
    public RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate() {
        RedisTemplate<String, Object> template = new RedisTemplate<>();
        template.setConnectionFactory(jedisConnectionFactory());
        return template;
    }
}
```

**Problem:** All the containers are running after docker compose up. but the connection between spring and redis can't be established.

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
slot-web-1    |     at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[na:na]
slot-web-1    |     at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:399) ~[na:na]
slot-web-1    |     at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:242) ~[na:na]
slot-web-1    |     at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:224) ~[na:na]
slot-web-1    |     at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[na:na]
```

Comment: Does it work if you start the spring-boot app locally and connect to `localhost` instead of `redis`?

Comment: @Turing85 yes it does

Comment: Just to be sure (although redis tends to start pretty fast): can you stage the start of the containers? `docker compose down && docker compose up -d redis && sleep 5 && docker compose up --build -d`

Comment: @Turing85 i'm pretty sure that redis is started first, i think "depends_on" setting already guarentees that.

Comment: `depends_on` only guarantees that the container is started first, but not that the service (contained within the container) is started before the depending container is started.

Comment: Then I am out of ideas.

Comment: @Turing85 sorry to mislead, i left it as localhost on my first try, then i tried with changing it to redis and now it works! (only another exception in mongo lol)

Comment: @Turing85 Is there a config that can be applied in docker-compose.yml for waiting services?

Comment: Sadly, no. There is no built-in way in doing this. There are, however [some workarounds](https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error may occur if your redis server is starting later than your spring boot. Make sure redis is started first by the following command.

```
docker compose down && docker compose up -d redis && sleep 5 && docker compose up --build -d
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if your container is on a remote server, you can use telnet on the server where the container is deployed to test whether it can connect to port 6379 of redis. If so, you can check whether the server has open port 6379, or a whitelist.
Secondly, you can try to connect to the 6379 port of the container redis by telnet on the computer.
If yes, you can check if the ip, password, username and other information of your redis configuration are correct.